# Accessing Matrix Elements by a "List of Points"

Tags: matlab

I have some large matrices of data, and a a two column matrix containing x and y locations, is there an easier way to work with the data elements corresponding to those points then:

```
for adj = 1:size(loc,1)
    testFunc(data1(loc(i,2),loc(i,1)), data2(loc(i,2),loc(i,1)), othervals)
end
```

Mostly I'm looking for a way to access the data elements by something closer to *data1(loc(i))*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to access elements of `data` via their linear indices. Linear indices increment first along the first dimension, then along the second dimension, and so on. For example the elements of a 3-by-2 array would be addressed in the following order

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

So to get element `(2,1)` of a 2-by-3 array via linear indexing, you would call `array(3)`. To convert between linear index and subscripts (such as the pair `2,3`), you can use `ind2sub` and `sub2ind`, respectively.

In your case, you'd run

```
linIdx = sub2ind(size(data),loc(:,2),loc(:,1))
```

if the first column of `loc` indexes into columns of `data`, and the second column of `loc` indexes into rows.

Then you can loop over `linIdx` to change your function call inside the loop to

```
testFunc(data1(linIdx(i)), data2(linIdx(i)), othervals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the x-y location into indices, and the use the indices to adress the matrix.
Then you can use arrayfun, to pally that your function to all elements.

```
ind=sub2ind(size(data1),location(:,1),location(:,2));
output=arrayfun(@(x,y) testFunc(x,y,othervals),data1(ind),data2(ind));
```

or if testFunc does not output a scalar:

```
output=arrayfun(@(x,y) testFunc(x,y,othervals),data1(ind),data2(ind),'UniformOutput',0);
```

Comment: testFunc is just a placeholder, I’ve got a lot more going on (math and various function calls on the matrix elements some of which use the x,y values for calculations) and what I really need is a way to more concisely access the matrix elements by some kind of “point” in a *ForEach* style loop. I can change the format of the point list as necessary.

Comment: Specifically, I have operations that run on points conditionally based on the result of other operations run on those points.